Ordinary Differential Equations and pursuit curves
In my studies on ordinary differential equations, in the book of title "Equações Diferencias Applicadas" of Djairo Guedes de Figeiredo, I found a problem involving persuit curves:
A boat located at the origin proposes to cross a river as shown in the figure

Knowing that the speed of the water is $v$ and that of the boat is $w$ and knowing that the boat always points to the point $(0,b)$. Determine the relationship that must exist between $v$ and $w$ for the boat to cross the river. Determine the trajectory of the boat in each case, that is, in the case in which the boat can cross and in the case in which the boat cannot cross.
He gives the following hints:
Use parametric repesentation $(x(t),y(t))$ of the trajetory depending on time $t$ and note that $$\frac{dx}{dt}=v-w\cos\theta,\quad \frac{dy}{dt}=w\sin\theta.$$
Use the relation $y-b=x \ \mathrm{tg} \  \theta$ in order to find
$$y'=\frac{b-y}{C\sqrt{x^2+(b-y)^2}}, \quad \mbox{where} \ \ C=\frac{v}{w}.$$
Actually, I have used the chain rule and I found
$$y'=\frac{b-y}{C\sqrt{x^2+(b-y)^2}-x}, \quad \mbox{where} \ \ C=\frac{v}{w}.$$
I have no idea of how solve any of these equations.
Helpe-me find the solution for the problem, please!

With the change of variable $y=b-z$, the last ODE becomes
$$
-z'=\frac{z}{C\sqrt{x^2+z^2}-x}. \tag{1}
$$
Eq. $(1)$ is homogeneous, so it can be transformed into a separable ODE with the change of variable $z=ux$:
\begin{align}
-u'x-u&=\frac{ux}{C\sqrt{x^2+u^2x^2}-x}=\frac{u}{C\sqrt{1+u^2}-1} \\
&\implies -u'x=\frac{Cu\sqrt{1+u^2}}{C\sqrt{1+u^2}-1} \\
&\implies \int\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{Cu\sqrt{1+u^2}}\right)du
=-\int\frac{dx}{x} \\
&\implies\ln(u)+\frac{1}{C}\coth^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+u^2}\right)=-\ln(x)+a \\
&\implies \ln (ux)+\frac{1}{C}\coth^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+u^2}\right)=a \\
&\implies \ln(b-y)+\frac{1}{C}\coth^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{b-y}{x}\right)^2}\right)=a. \tag{2}
\end{align}
To determine the constant of integration $a$, we use the initial condition $y(0)=0$:
$$
a=\ln(b)+\underbrace{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{C}\coth^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)^2}\right)}_{=\,0}
=\ln(b). \tag{3}
$$
Therefore, the solution to the last ODE in the OP is given, in implicit form, by
$$
\ln\left(1-\frac{y}{b}\right)+\frac{1}{C}\coth^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{b-y}{x}\right)^2}\right)=0, \tag{4}
$$
or, isolating $x$, by
$$
x=(y-b)\sinh\left(C\ln\left(1-\frac{y}{b}\right)\right). \tag{5}
$$
I leave to you the analysis of the solution.
